# Using definition file without a module

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I'm trying to use this definition file in my project (Angular):
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/websql

But it doesn't export any modules, so how do I import it in a TypeScript file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import anything. Just use the types as you use `Window`, `Document` or others. The types are acknowledged automatically by TypeScript, and you don't need to import anything to use websql, as the browser context provides the API